# Which logics cannot be "approximated" with real-valued semantics when the connectives are restricted to be continuous?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Which logics lack a real-valued semantics when the connectives are restricted to be continuous?

For the purposes of this question, I will assume that classical logic has the signature $\{\lnot, \to\}$ and will treat $\top$ and $\bot$ as derived rather than primitive.

---

This question is inspired by the notion of [a Kripke frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_modal_logic) from modal logic and of a [Routley-Meyer model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic#Routley%E2%80%93Meyer_models) from the semantics of relevance logic. I'm curious about what different kinds of frames can and cannot do.

Let a real-valued semantics be the set $[0, 1]$, equipped with a family of connectives $\mathcal{F}$ and a set $E \subset [0,1]$ of designated truth values. Let the designated truth values be constrained to satisfy the following property.

Let $x, y$ be elements of $[0,1]$.

$$ \text{If $x$ is in $E$ and $x < y$, then $y$ is in $E$.} $$

Let $M$ be some particular real-valued semantics. $M \models \varphi$ holds if and only if the interpretation of $\varphi$ is in $E^M$.

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a set of real-valued semantics and let $\mathcal{X} \models \varphi$ hold if and only if $M \models \varphi$ holds for each $M$ in $\mathcal{X}$.

If I impose no constraints whatsoever on the connectives, then I can get classical logic in the following way.

I will now define $M_0$. Let $E = \{1\}$.
Let the interpretation of $a \to b$ be $0$ when $a$ is designated and $b$ is not designated. Let the interpretation of $a \to b$ be $1$ otherwise.

Let the interpretation of $\lnot a$ be the interpretation of $a\to 0$.

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be equal to $\{M_0\}$.

Certain constraints we may choose to impose on the elements of $\mathcal{X}$ will fail to exclude the trivial solution. For example, constraining each element of $\mathcal{X}$ to have piecewise constant connectives will not exclude $\{M_0\}$.

Constraining the interpretations of the connectives to be *continuous*, on the other hand, seems intuitively like it will cause some problems.

However, it seems pretty clear that we approximate the $\to$ of $M_0$ arbitrarily well with a sequence of continuous values for $[\to] : [0,1] \times [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ and get our $\mathcal{X}$ that way.

I'm wondering if there's a nice characterization of logics that *can't* be approximated in this way (or equivalently, ones that *can*).